# Using $('#foo').val() == $('#foo').is(':checked') never ends in true?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I go about comparing those two variables?

Here is my code:

```
if ($('#<%= CheckBox1.ClientID %>').val() != $('#<%= CheckBox1.ClientID %>').is(':checked')) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Which always returns true.

How can I compare these two values? I'm trying to capture the checkboxes last state and see if it is the same as the current one. Thanks!

Comment: .is(":checked") will always return a boolean value and .val() will always return a string value. In what case do you expect the two to be equal?

Comment: What are you trying to compare?  Those return different things.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks, did String() on the .is(":checked") and it allowed me to compare the two.

Answer (score 0):

You have a fundamental error in your understanding of a checkbox and the .val() function.

```
<input id="test" type="checkbox" value="ValueToReturnIfChecked" name="WhateverToUseInYourPost" />

$("#test").val() //will return "ValueToReturnIfChecked.

$("#test").is(":checked") //will return true or false.

$("#test").prop("checked") //will return true or false.

$("#test").attr("checked") //will return checked or empty string
```

**Edit: Additional Clarification**

I guess I should answer your actual question.  The answer is you CANNOT compare *.val() to *.is(":checked") they are fundamentally different.  If you want to track past state you can always do:

```
$("#test").on("click", function(){
     $this = $(this);
     if($this.data("priorState") == $this.is(":checked")){
          //Do something
     }else{
          //The following will inject the state into the checkbox so you can track it.
          $this.data("priorState", $this.is(":checked"))
     }

});
```